# Pause Canvas game with boolean

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm creating a HTML5 Canvas game, if the P, key is pressed (keycode 80) the game will pause. If the key is pressed a second time, the game  will continue. Is there an easy way to toggle the isPaused boolean every time the P key is pressed? Here is my code thus far:

```
    var isPaused = false;   

  function checkKey(e, value) {
  var keyID = e.keyCode || e.which;

  if (keyID === 38) { // Up arrow
    player1.isUpKey = value;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (keyID === 80) { 
    isPaused = !isPaused; 
}

}
```

// game loop

```
    function step() {
      setTimeout(function() {

        if (!isPaused) {  
          update();  // controls character movement
        }  

  draw();
    requestAnimFrame(step);
  }, 30); 
}
```

Many thanks,

Comment: don't mix setTimeout and requestAnimationFrame like that !

Comment: Also, be sure to call `checkKey` only when the key is really pressed (first key down event). Use a boolean array to store the state for each key when a key is pressed/released and call `checkKey` when the state changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can invert the boolean by using:

```
isPaused = !isPaused;  // ! = NOT which will invert it
```

Likewise you can use a similar toggle switch to reduce frame rate to 30 FPS instead of using `setTimeout`:

```
var skipFrame = true;

function step() {
  skipFrame = !skipFrame;
  if (skipFrame || isPaused) {
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
    return
  }

  update();
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

Comment: It'll reduce frame rate to 72 FPS on 144Hz monitors, because `requestAnimationFrame` limit the FPS to the refresh rate of the monitor. The best way to limit framerate is to use `setTimeout` only with some time calculations to have a constant framerate.

Comment: @Nasso sure, for those few who have one. The better way (IMO) is to measure the time differences between each frame and let the update code through when ~33ms has passed, but that was outside the scope of this q.

Comment: Thanks this works but there is a problem. If i press 'P' the boolean is set to true and the game is paused. However when the is isn't pressed the boolean value reverts back to false and the game continues

Comment: @stckpete I think the last sentence there came out wrong.. if you could post the code for how the checkKey is triggered we could look at it as well.